# Does signal strength increment mean an increment on data speed?

Tags: antenna

For a WLAN antenna, if the signal strength is increased, can I expect higher SNR, lower bit error rate(BER) and higher data speed?

Answer (score 0):

The access point and client (station) will negotiate a channel coding (MCS) based on each other’s *received* signal strength. So boosting the power at the AP might let the partners bump up to a faster rate, but only if the AP can also see a strong enough signal from the client to do that.